# Why isn't justify-items working in css grid, even though there is enough space in the box?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am new to coding, and I pretty much understand html/css but for some reason, I am unable to figure out why I can't get my content to justify to the end of the box even though there is space in the container. I even placed a border around the elements to be sure. Please help me figure this out.

[image]

This is my html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="./resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </link>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bryan Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="grid1">
      <div class="spacer-left"></div>
      <div class="header-left"><img id="logo" src="./resources/logo/letterLogo.png"></div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <ul class="social-media">
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>Main</li>
          <li>Projects</li>
          <li>Videos</li>
          <li>Photography</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer-right"></div>

    </div>

  </header>
  <div id="jumbotron">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my css:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 body{
   background: color #f8f8f8;
   color: #262626;
 }
 
header{padding-top: 20px;}

#grid1{ 
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 5% 1fr 1fr 5%;
 grid-auto-rows: 50px;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;

}
.header-left{
 grid-column-start: 2;
 grid-column-end: 3;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;
}
.header-right{
 
justify-self: end;
align-self: center;
 grid-column-start: 3;
 grid-column-end: 4;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;
 
}

.social-media{
 border: 1px red solid;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 2;
}

nav{
 grid-row-start: 2;
 grid-row-end: 3;
}
li{
 display: inline;
}
#logo{
 max-height: 100px;

}
.sm-icon{
max-height: 25px;
border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.social-media` is not a grid layout.
The container takes up the whole row but the inline elements will start from the left by default.
You can use flexbox to align items to the end (right):

```
.social-media {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now I know grid only affects the child directly...

Answer (score -1):

```
just use direct alignment style in the class.
.social-media {
  text-align: right;
}
   //or
.social-media {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 body{
   background: color #f8f8f8;
   color: #262626;
 }
 
header{padding-top: 20px;}

#grid1{ 
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 5% 1fr 1fr 5%;
 grid-auto-rows: 50px;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;

}
.header-left{
 grid-column-start: 2;
 grid-column-end: 3;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;
}
.header-right{
 
justify-self: end;
align-self: center;
 grid-column-start: 3;
 grid-column-end: 4;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;
 
}

.social-media{
 border: 1px red solid;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 2;
 text-align: right;
}

nav{
 grid-row-start: 2;
 grid-row-end: 3;
}
li{
 display: inline;
}
#logo{
 max-height: 100px;

}
.sm-icon{
max-height: 25px;
border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="./resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </link>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bryan Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="grid1">
      <div class="spacer-left"></div>
      <div class="header-left"><img id="logo" src="./resources/logo/letterLogo.png"></div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <ul class="social-media">
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>Main</li>
          <li>Projects</li>
          <li>Videos</li>
          <li>Photography</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer-right"></div>

    </div>

  </header>
  <div id="jumbotron">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 body{
   background: color #f8f8f8;
   color: #262626;
 }
 
header{padding-top: 20px;}

#grid1{ 
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 5% 1fr 1fr 5%;
 grid-auto-rows: 50px;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;

}
.header-left{
 grid-column-start: 2;
 grid-column-end: 3;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;
}
.header-right{
 
justify-self: end;
align-self: center;
 grid-column-start: 3;
 grid-column-end: 4;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 3;
 
}

.social-media{
 border: 1px red solid;
 grid-row-start: 1;
 grid-row-end: 2;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav{
 grid-row-start: 2;
 grid-row-end: 3;
}
li{
 display: inline;
}
#logo{
 max-height: 100px;

}
.sm-icon{
max-height: 25px;
border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="./resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </link>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bryan Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="grid1">
      <div class="spacer-left"></div>
      <div class="header-left"><img id="logo" src="./resources/logo/letterLogo.png"></div>
      <div class="header-right">
        <ul class="social-media">
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
          <li><img class="sm-icon" src="./resources/images/facebook-black.png"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>Main</li>
          <li>Projects</li>
          <li>Videos</li>
          <li>Photography</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer-right"></div>

    </div>

  </header>
  <div id="jumbotron">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please share an explanation to answer the question.

Comment: @Uwe I put it at the beginning of the answer.

 .social-media {
  text-align: right;
}
   //or
.social-media {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}

Comment: please explain your answer, try using code format for code only, tell us why you have 3 code blocks.

Comment: @stramin I got the same code as the question used.
I just adjusted the css alignment.
has 2 examples because I showed 2 different ways to solve.

Comment: Please edit the answer writing that, something like: "This is a way to do it using X: `first code here` And this is another way to do it if you don´t have Y or need Z: `another code here`", this way people will understand what you are proposing without need to read the comments :)